# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.text::TextField@1182e101 to flash.display.MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am fairly new to actionscript 3.0, and I keep getting the error above. My code is

```
stop();
Lamp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,lookatlamp);
function lookatlamp(event:MouseEvent){
Dialogue.text = "It is a very bright lamp. It hurts your eyes.";
}
Room.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,standup);
function standup(event:MouseEvent){
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Frame 2:

```
stop();
Table.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,lookatthetable);
function lookatthetable(event:MouseEvent){
gotoAndStop(4);
}
FirstDoor.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotonextroom);
function gotonextroom(event:MouseEvent){
gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

frame 3:

```
stop();
Inspctdr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,lookatthedoor);
function lookatthedoor(event:MouseEvent){
Dialogue.text = "It is a metal door with a shiny silver handle.";
}
```

and the full error is:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.text::TextField@119c83d1 to flash.display.MovieClip.

at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/standup()
```

and

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.text::TextField@119c8449 to flash.display.MovieClip.

at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/lookatthetable()
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: I figured out what I did. My text box was a media clip instead of a dynamic text box. Thank you all who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **Dialogue** is not a textField.  Is **Dialogue** a MovieClip with a textfield inside?  If so, give the textField inside an instance name like **tf**.

Then set the text like:

```
Dialogue.tf.text = 'some text';
```